# How can I define a type in Initialstate in Redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to define a type for the initial value in the slice state. But I don't know what to do.

If I input null in singlePost, I get this red line warning.

but I want to specify the type of the initial value of singlePost.

[image]

singlePost will contain these values.

[image]

this is my code

```
    // singlePost = {
    //   Comments: [
    //      {id: 46, content: "hello", createdAt: "2022-04-30T08:24:15.000Z", 
    //   }
    //   {id: 47, content: "zz", createdAt: "2022-04-30T08:24:30.000Z",
    // ],

    // Images: [
    //   PostId: 61
    //   createdAt: "2022-04-27T08:17:51.000Z"
    //   id: 6
    //   src: "bd8b355e-cfe8-4c50-be4c-6c4958958fc6.JPEG"
    //   updatedAt: "2022-04-27T08:17:51.000Z"]

    //   Likecomments: [{},{}]

    //   Likers: [{}]

    //   User:{id:2, nickname:'elon'}

    //   content:"helloword"

    //   createdAt:"22022-212"

    //   id: 61,

    //   updatedAt:"asdasd"
    // }


    export const initialState = {

      singlePost: null,

    }
    const postSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'post',
      initialState,
      reducers: {},
      extraReducers: builder =>
        builder

          .addCase(addComment.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<test>) => {

            const post = state.mainPosts.find(v => v.id === action.payload.PostId);

            state.addCommentLoading = false;
            state.addCommentDone = true;
            state.singlePost.Comments.push(action.payload);
            post.Comments.push(action.payload);
          })

          .addDefaultCase(state => state),
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface IImage {
  PostId: number;
  createdAt: string;
  id: number;
  //....
}

interface IComment {
  id: number;
  content: string;
  createdAt: string;
}

inteface ISinglePost {
    Comments: IComment[] | null;
    Images?: IImage[];
}

interface IInitialState {
  singlePost: ISinglePost | null;
}

export const initialState: IInitialState = {

  singlePost: null,

}
```

Comment: i used your code but Warning with red line on siglepost it says
(property) IInitialState.singlePost: {
    Comments?: IComment[] | null | undefined;
    Images?: IImage[] | undefined;
}
Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ Comments?: IComment[] | null | undefined; Images?: IImage[] | undefined; }'.ts(2322)
post.ts(108, 3): The expected type comes from property 'singlePost' which is declared here on type 'IInitialState'

Comment: @user15322469 sorry, my bad, I've changed my answer a bit, now it should work.

Comment: @user15322469 glad that I helped

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples [in the docs for createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice).

You need an interface

```
interface MySliceState {
  singlePost: null | {
    Comments: Array<{
      id: number,
      content: string,
      ...
    }>,
    Images: ...,
    ...
  }
}
```

and then assert that `inialState` is of that type.

```
    const initialState = {

      singlePost: null,

    } as MySliceState
```